# Open Safari's native share extensions from browser

Tags: ios8-share-extension, wechat

Does anyone know if its possible to create a button embedded in a web page which pops up safari's native share extensions window?

[image: Native Share Extensions]

I'm essentially trying to find a hack around the fact that i can't create a WeChat share button, this seems like a viable way round.

Note: has to be web tech, not iOS or Android.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is now supported on a limited set of browsers. I found this article explaining how to do it and where it's supported: https://alligator.io/js/web-share-api/